# How to run Apache Flink as a library inside Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-flink

Is there a way to run Apache Flink as a part of Spring Boot application? Which jar files should we add to our gradle? How should we start Apache Flink application system inside our spring boot service? We want to consume messages from RabbitMQ and run stream analytics with Java.

Comment: Any luck with the solution?

Comment: no, used RX Java instead.

Comment: Any reference or working demo ?